# Stop posts from being displayed after certain day

Tags: php, pagination

I have just created a pagination function for a travel company. There are two things I want to change that I can't figure out.

1. Each trip has a date. What i want to be able to do is stop the trip from displaying in the list one the day of the trip and all subsequent days. I have a rough idea, but that doesn't seem to work.

> ```
> if (date($row['date'])  getdate()) { 
>    // echo trip info here
> }
> ```

-2. After each of the trips in the list there is a seperator (is that the right word?) to separate each trip's info. On the last trip if the page I don't want that seperator. I have no clue how to do this :/

Thanks in advance for any help & advice.

```
                    <?php

                if (isset($_GET["p"])) { $page  = $_GET["p"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
                $start_from = ($page-1) * 4; 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM destinations ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT $start_from, 4"; 
                $result = mysqli_query ($con,$sql);



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'>";
                    echo "<img src='" . $row ['img'] . "' alt='' class='img-responsive'>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='col-md-8 col-sm-8'>";
                    echo "<h2><a href='" . $row ['url'] . "'>" . $row ['name'] . "</a></h2>";
                    echo "<ul class='blog-info'>";
                        echo "<li><i class='icon-calendar'></i> " . date("d/m/y", strtotime($row['date'])) . "</li>";
                    echo "</ul>";
                   echo $row ['description'];
                    echo "<a class='btn theme-btn' href='" . $row ['url'] . "'>View Details <i class='icon-angle-right'></i></a>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<hr class='blog-post-sep'>";
  }

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(trip_id) FROM destinations"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 4); 

echo "<div class='text-center'> <ul class='pagination pagination-centered'>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<li><a href='routea.php?p=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; 
};
echo "</ul></div>";
```

mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: Why don't you do the first part in your SQL query? `WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE()`?

Comment: @Barmar , well that was easy. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your SQL to filter out the unwanted trips:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM destinations
   WHERE date  < CURRENT_DATE()
   ORDER BY date ASC 
   LIMIT $start_from, 4
   ```
2. You can solve it with CSS:

   ```css
   hr.blog-post-sep:last-of-type {
       display: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry, now that they don't display the trips the pagination function still thinks it's there and displays and blank page. Any ideas?

Comment: Put the same condition in the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query.